# Better to read the whole file, close it, and then loop over it, or loop over while it's open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-read

I was wondering, which of these is the better and safer way to process a file's contents line by line. The assumption here is that the file's contents are very critical, but  the file is not very large, so memory consumption is not an issue.

Is it better to close the file as soon as possible using this:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    do_something(line)
```

Or to just loop over it in one go:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

Which of these practises is generally the better and the more accepted way of doing it?

Comment: If you are talking about a huge file, second method is probably more efficient in terms of memory usage, because you don't store the entire lines beforehand.

Comment: @Austin, OP stated that memory isn't an issue.  However, OP mentioned criticality and the first question that comes to mind is rollback/backout.  Is it better to process the whole contents of the file and back out of the whole file if an issue arises?  Or, is it better to process some of the contents of the file, and if an issue does occur then do you rollback the committed lines or are you OK with the already processed lines and just replay the remaining?  I think determining the criticality of your file (on how to handle failure events) will drive your choice of loop.

Comment: Rollback only seems to be an issue if you are *writing* to a file; for read-only access to a file, it doesn't matter if you are iterating with a file iterator or a list iterator. That's just a matter of memory management.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "better" solution. Simply because these two are **far** from being equivalent.

The first one loads entire file into memory and then processes the in-memory data. This has a potential advantage of being faster depending on what the processing is. Note that if the file is bigger than the amount of RAM you have then this is not an option at all.

The second one loads only a piece of the file into memory, processes it and then loads another piece and so on. This is generally slower (although it is likely you won't see the difference because often the processing time, especially in Python, dominates the reading time) but drastically reduces memory consumption (assuming that your file has more than 1 line). Also in some cases it may be more difficult to work with. For example say that you are looking for a specific pattern `xy\nz` in the file. Now with "line by line" loading you have to remember previous line in order to do a correct check. Which is more difficult to implement (but only a bit). So again: it depends on what you are doing.

As you can see there are tradeoffs and what is better depends on your context. I often do this: if file is relatively small (say up to few hundred megabytes) then load it into memory.

Now you've mentioned that the content is "critical". I don't know what that means but for example if you are trying to make updates to the file atomic or reads consistent between processes then this is a very different problem from the one you've posted. And generally hard so I advice using a proper database. SQLite is an easy option (again: depending on your scenario) similar to having a file.

Comment: The file iterator is already performing some amount of buffering itself; you aren't literally reading a single line from disk at a time.

Comment: @chepner Sure, there's also OS caching, and disk caching. Also the file may already be in RAM (i.e. ram disk). But these are all implementation details. The general idea stays the same: you read only a piece from somewhere (wherever that is). Not everything.

Comment: Yes, but it leaves the details of memory management to someone else. It's hardly likely that the overhead of interleaving I/O with processing is going to make reading the entire file into memory significantly faster by comparison.

Comment: @chepner I won't argue with that because I haven't measured the speed to be honest. I've modified the answer a bit and also added "difficulty" as an argument against "read line by line".